# Where are the global Lint settings stored?

Tags: android, eclipse, lint

In my Android project I have several projects in the workspace. Each project has its own lint.xml setting file. On top of that Eclipse offers a way to set default lint options in "Preferences-Android-Lint Error Checking" that apply to all projects.

Is there some global lint.xml file where these settings are stored? Or some other way to easily copy these settings between installations of Eclipse? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can Export/Import Preferences to use same settings across multiple `Eclipse` installations.

There is nothing specific to Lint settings but Export/Import Preferences will do the job. Please try following steps:

1. **File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> Next**
2. Select 'Export all' (or any specific preference), select the export file path and click 'Finish' button.

In the new `Eclipse` installation do following:

1. **File -> Import -> General -> Preferences -> Next**
2. Select the exported preferences file and select 'Import all' (or any specific preference) and click 'Finish' button.
3. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Global Lint settings (or at least some of them) are stored in file com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs, located in ...\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings directory.

Example of settings file content:
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.lintSeverities=InlinedApi\=INFORMATIONAL,LocalSuppress\=IGNORE
...